# is there some sort of catchable trigger when one writes/deletes a new file in linux?

Tags: linux, rsync, synchronization, write

I would like a simple tool for syncing two folders on remote servers...

Utopically, I only need an OS catchable trigger (or something like that) that could be used to fire rsync automatically ?

Is there anything of the sort, or a simple tool capable of doing this ?

rsync each minute is not at all an elegant solution to the problem ... i would like to call rsync each time a file is written/deleted in any one of the servers, in a specific folder...

the goal is to easily maintain to remote folders in sync

update: maybe something like [gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/)... ?

thanks !

arod

Answer (score 3):

In [my answer to this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/146961/automatically-run-a-command-every-time-a-file-is-changed/146975#146975), I suggested [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). It's easy to set up system-wide and user-specific config files in a manner similar to `cron`. You can specify scripts that will be run when filesystem events are triggered. It uses the Linux kernel inotify API. You might take a look at it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Ooh, that's cool. I'll need to add that to my toolbox for future usage.

Comment: Ooh +1, I feel smarter just for now knowing that exists.

Comment: i notify is very cool ! it does not, however, monitor sub directory's... : (

Comment: @arod: That's true, `inotify` doesn't do recursive monitoring. You would need to add an `incron` rule for each specific directory.

Comment: yep, and thats a bit cumbersome... directories pop in and out of existence erraticaly ; )

Answer (score 2):

Try *inotify*. For your relative simple requirements this should be best suited.

An example script:

```
while { inotifywait -e create -e delete /directory2watch; }; do
  echo rsync -avz /directory2watch
done
```

Or something like that.

With inotify you have access to those events:

- access – file was accessed
- modify – file was modified
- attrib – file attributes changed
- close_write – file closed, after being opened in writeable mode
- close_nowrite – file closed, after being opened in read-only mode
- close – file closed, regardless of read/write mode
- open – file was opened
- move – a file within watched directory was moved
- create – a file was created within watched directory
- delete – a file was deleted within watched directory
- delete_self – the watched file was deleted
- unmount – file system on which watched file exists was unmounted

Comment: inotify is excellen, but it get cumbersome when tracking directories and subdirectories...

Comment: At least inotifywait knows the `-r` option for recursive monitoring. I don't know how good it works though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) will do just what you need. It works at the block device level, so if you don't want to maintain a separate partition for this synchronized data, you can just create a disk image and mount it loopback, using DRBD to keep things in sync with the remote server.

Comment: it's right that using DRBD sound like the right solution, things like "you can just create a disk image and mount it loopback" are not so clear. 
i didnt like drbd because i needed to store my files in a different partition, seems like to big a solution for syncing a couple of folders... 
if you could explain how to "create a disk image and mount it loopback", can this be used to sync a couple of folders ? thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution here is [afs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System)

There all sorts of complications using DRBD on anything but a small LAN with high levels of connectivity between nodes.

But you could roll your own solution using [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify)

Comment: afs seems very cool, and very suited to my needs, i'll take a look ! thank you very much ! : )